# Get filename with extension from url on log string using PHP PCRE regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a script for parsing a log file from an network device. The log file generated from the device it's not regular, the lines doesn't follow a logic sequence and haves multiple patterns. My script needs to extract from the log lines only the ones that matches an specific pattern and from that lines specific information as datetime, entry type, resource type and resource name from the url in the string. The pattern that I need to match it's the following:

*dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss INFO spx.resource.media   - New Resource 'URI' [flags] (dlc/tcd)*

where 'INFO' is the entry type, 'spx.resource.media' the resource type and in the URI resides the resource name. Currently we need to filter those that haves a specifics extensions.

I reviewed several posts that cover this subject and using this online [tool](https://regex101.com/): I came with this regular expresion:

```
/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s{1,}(\w{4})\s{1,}(spx.resource.media)(.{1,}(?<=(?:.jpg)|(?:.png)))/g
```

The problem is that the last regex group matches the whole URI plus the characters and spaces from the resource type and on, and y only need the filename with the extension. I tried this 'regex-to-get-a-filename-from-a-url' (can't post the link insufficient reputation) but doesn't workout 'cause the debugger marks the ^/ as unescaped delimiter. Also if removed doesn't work. A portion of the log can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wKYvckMgqXV2VDelVPLThKWTA/view?usp=sharing). I really need to get this.

Thanks for reading and/or answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month ago a came with a solution. What I wanted was to extract the filename and the rest of the subgroups with one pattern, I don´t know if this is possible but with my current regex skills is not. So what I did was to use three regex patterns as you can see in the code below:

This code is part of a class that I (obviously) called Parser. First I define the patterns as constants in the class.

```
/**
 * @const string Log line pattern
 */
const LINE_REGEX_PATTERN = '/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s{1,}(\w{4})\s{1,}(spx.resource.media)(.{1,}(?<=%extensions%))/';

/**
 * @const string Full URL pattern
 */
const FULL_URL_PATTERN = '/\b((?:https?|ftps?|file|spx):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/i';

/**
 * @const string Filename pattern
 */
const RESOURCE_REGEX_PATTERN = '/((?:[^\/][\d\w\.-]+)(?<=%extensions%))/';
```

As you can see, I use a placeholder for the file extensions because in this case I need them to be dynamically set by configuration or database query. Next I validate each extracted line against the first pattern

```
/**
 * Line extract
 *
 * @param string $file_line File line string
 *
 * @return array An array if matches
 *               Array (
 *                  [0] => Matched line
 *                  [1] => Date\Time subgroup (format >> d-M-y H:i:s)
 *                  [2] => String flag subgroup
 *                  [3] => Resource type subgroup (not used)
 *                  [4] => Text string containing resource URL
 *               )
 *               , null otherwise
 *
 * @throws RegexException If malformed pattern
 */
private function extractMatches($file_line)
{
    $extensions = array();

    // build valid extensions subgroup
    foreach ($this->valid_extensions as $extension) {
        $extensions[] = sprintf("(?:\.%s)", $extension);
    }

    $matches = array();
    // replace extensions placeholder
    $pattern  = str_replace('%extensions%', implode('|', $extensions), self::LINE_REGEX_PATTERN);
    $is_valid = preg_match($pattern, $file_line, $matches);

    if ($is_valid === false) {
        throw new RegexException();
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

From the resulting array (if any) I fetch the 5th element (the one that stores the text with the URL in it), then I passed to two other functions, the first one to full URL extraction and the second one to finally extract the filename. See below:

```
/**
 * Full URL extract
 *
 * @param string $text Text with URL in it
 *
 * @return string The URL, empty string otherwise
 *
 * @throws RegexException If malformed pattern
 */
private function extractUrl($text)
{
    $match    = array();
    $is_valid = preg_match(self::FULL_URL_PATTERN, $text, $match);

    if ($is_valid === false) {
        throw new RegexException();
    } elseif ($is_valid === 1) {
        return $match[0];
    }

    return ''; // No URL found!
}

/**
 * Filename extract
 *
 * @param string $url Resource URL (expects no GET parameters)
 *
 * @return string Resource filename (includes extension), empty string otherwise
 *
 * @throws RegexException If malformed pattern
 */
private function extractResourceNameFromUrl($url)
{
    $extensions = array();

    // build valid extensions subgroup
    foreach ($this->valid_extensions as $extension) {
        $extensions[] = sprintf("(?:\.%s)", $extension);
    }

    $matches = array();
    // replace extensions placeholder
    $pattern  = str_replace('%extensions%', implode('|', $extensions), self::RESOURCE_REGEX_PATTERN);
    $is_valid = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

    if ($is_valid === false) {
        throw new RegexException();
    } elseif ($is_valid === 1) {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return '';
}
```

Finally some where in my app I just did:

```
$parser = new Parser();
// fetch file line loop
$matches = $parser->extractMatches($file_line);
$url = $parser->extractUrl($matches[4]);
$filename = $parser->extractResourceNameFromUrl($matches[4]);
```

Hope helps somebody. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this. First Identify the location of the file then you can loop through accordingly to get what you want

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    echo $buffer;
}
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I got no problems reading the file content, what I'm trying to do is extract each line if it matches the regex with preg_grep I can get each match as index of an array. The question here is the regex not the file access, but thanks for answering.